# "Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate" error

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Xcode always says "No code signing identities found" when I work on a new project.

Normally, I just press fix issue, and it works. But since a while, it keeps saying "Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate". When I try to press "Reset" in Xcode 7.2, nothing happens, other than that I get a email that my certificate was revoked. I still get the same error. I also tried the Xcode beta, when I press "Reset" there, it says "Certificate installation failed".

I'm a free(not paid) apple developer, so I don't have access to the member center. I also haven't got a mac that has got the old certificate, otherwise I could just import it from  there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently WWDR certificate expired(actually on 14/02.2016) and this caused a lot of issues. You could try downloading the new one:

https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

This is not a part of the development program and you don't need access to member center in order to download it.

Keep in mind to remove the old one from Keychain access in both Login and System(you may need to check View->Show expired certificates if it doesn't appear).

Comment: Everything works again. Thank you very much! I also had to reset my keychain, because it was corrupted somehow.